# How should I redirect to newsletter confirmation page after form submit in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, html-formhandler

After submitting the form the external link to the newsletter confirmation page should open and it working as expected in local but in production, it is redirecting to `siteUrl/undefined`

```
<form
        action={`${revueConfigValue}`}
        method="post"
        id="revue-form"
        name="revue-form"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <Flex gap={2} justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
          <Box>
            <Input
              width={"100%"}
              variant={"solid"}
              borderWidth={1}
              color={"gray.800"}
              _placeholder={{
                color: "gray.400",
              }}
              borderColor={useColorModeValue("gray.300", "gray.700")}
              id="member_email"
              name="member[email]"
              type={"email"}
              required
              placeholder={"Your Email"}
              aria-label={"Your Email"}
              value={email}
              onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setEmail(e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              value="Subscribe"
              name="member[subscribe]"
              id="member_submit"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </form>
```

It can be something silly I might be missing or silly, I don't know and couldn't find any solution for searching for a while any help would be appreciated! In am using revue newsletter if that matters.

Comment: Do you mean that `revueConfigValue` is resolving to `'siteUrl/undefined'`?

Comment: @David yes that is true and the actual value of `revueConfigValue` is "https://www.getrevue.co/profile/revueProfileName/add_subscriber", I am confused because it's working as expected in local.

Comment: In that case the code shown isn't the source of the problem.  If the runtime value of `revueConfigValue` isn't what you expect then you need to examine/debug where that value is coming from.  The code shown doesn't include anything about that.

Comment: @David so I checked you are right, the env value is coming as "undefined" in production, it's very confusing even in build it's working fine, I cannot come to any conclusion. So let me give more information, i think it should be explained in the question, aplogies.

`const revueConfigValue: string = process.env.REACT_APP_REVUE_PROFILE_NAME as string;`

This from where the value is coming, it's is stored in env as you can see! I hope this can help!